# How to create a listview for the items which are stored in database?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

As i am creating a application, There is one Registration form that contains radio button,spinner,checkboxes and some EditText as the user fills the registration form and clicking on submit button it saves in database.
After that i want to show all the items in a listview.
My question is how to display the data in ListView ?

Comment: there are 2 separate tasks: 1. Load items from DB. 2. display items in ListView.

Comment: can u please provide me the code @ Vlad Matvienko

Comment: @AnjaliPatel You want to display only one record in listview? First of all you have to fetch the data from database and then give that data to listview.

Comment: No,i want to display the whole records present in database. @Pratik Dasa

Comment: ya so just fetch data from database and display it, what the problem are you getting in it? @AnjaliPatel

Comment: @AnjaliPatel Have you done this or not?

Comment: yes,Its done @PratikDasa

Answer (score 0):

There are so many examples, how to populate listView with the data.

Suggestion: Create a Adapter to populate listView which will extend CursorAdapter.

Read about cursorAdapter [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)

Here are some examples:

[Example 1](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter)

[Example 2](https://coderwall.com/p/fmavhg/android-cursoradapter-with-custom-layout-and-how-to-use-it)

Comment below in case of any help.

Comment: can u provide me the working sample project. It would be a great help @ Sangeeta

Comment: These examples are with code only. please go through first.

Comment: I already did it.As i'm a beginner in Android so getting confused where to write the code.

Comment: @AnjaliPatel, if you don't know where to write the code, then you should firstly go through very basics before starting working on Android projects